# Sorting array for Binary Search

Tags: java, arrays, performance, sorting

I have an array of objects (telephone directory entries, stored in the form `Entry( surname,initials,extension)` ) which I would like to search efficiently. In order to do this I'm trying to use `Arrays.binarySearch()`. I have two separate methods for searching the array, one using names and the other using numbers. The array is sorted by Surname in alphabetical order as I insert each element in the correct place in my `addEntry()` method. I can use `binarySearch()` when searching by name as the array is sorted in alphabetical order, but the problem I have is the array is not sorted when I search by number. I have overridden `compareTo()` in my Entry class for comparing surnames, but when I search by number I need to sort my array in ascending order of numbers, I am unsure how to do this?

```
public int lookupNumberByName(String surname, String initials) {

    int index = 0;
    if (countElements() == directory.length) {
        Entry lookup = new Entry(surname, initials);
        index = Arrays.binarySearch(directory, lookup);
    }
    else if (countElements() != directory.length) {
        Entry[] origArray = directory;
        Entry[] cutArray = Arrays
                .copyOfRange(directory, 0, countElements());
        directory = cutArray;
        Entry lookup = new Entry(surname, initials);
        index = Arrays.binarySearch(directory, lookup);
        directory = origArray;
    }
    return index;
}
```

I would like to do something like this for my `LookupByNumber()` method -

```
public int LookupByNumber(int extension) {
    Entry[] origArray1 = directory;
    Entry[] cutArray1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(directory, 0, countElements());
    directory = cutArray1;
    Arrays.sort(directory); //sort in ascending order of numbers
    Entry lookup1 = new Entry(extension);
    int index1 = Arrays.binarySearch(directory, lookup1);
    String surname1 = directory[index1].getSurname();
    String initals1 = directory[index1].getInitials();
    directory = origArray1;

    int arrayPos = lookupNumberByName(surname1,initials1);

    return arrayPos;
```

My `compareTo` method -

```
public int compareTo(Entry other) {
    return this.surname.compareTo(other.getSurname());
}
```

Help very much appreciated

edit - I realize arrays are not the best data structure for this, but I have been specifically asked to use an array for this task.

Update - How exactly does `sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)` work? when I try writing my own  `Comparator` -

```
public class numberSorter implements Comparator<Entry> {
@Override
public int compare(Entry o1, Entry o2) {
    if (o1.getExtension() > o2.getExtension()) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (o1.getExtension() == o2.getExtension()) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (o1.getExtension() < o2.getExtension()) {
        return -1;
    }
    return -1;
}
}
```

And calling `Arrays.sort(directory,new numberSorter());` I get the following exception -

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.String.compareTo(Unknown Source)
at project.Entry.compareTo(Entry.java:45)
at project.Entry.compareTo(Entry.java:1)
at java.util.Arrays.binarySearch0(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(Unknown Source)
at project.ArrayDirectory.LookupByNumber(ArrayDirectory.java:128)
at project.test.main(test.java:29)
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than keeping the Entry objects in Arrays, keep them in Maps.  For example, you'd have one Map that mapped the Surname to the Entry, and another that mapped the Extension to the Entry.  You can then efficiently look up the entry by Surname or Extension by calling the get() method on the appropriate Map.

If the Map is a TreeMap, the lookup is about the same speed as a binary search (O log(n)).  If you use a HashMap, it can be even faster once you get a large number of entries.